# determine data type while iterating through hashmap in java

Tags: java, casting, hashmap, runtime

Is it possible to inspect data type of value while iterating through `HashMap<String,Object>`?

```
while(iterator.hasNext) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
    String key = pairs.getKey();
   <Type> value = (Type) pairs.getValue();        
}
```

The map has a combination of `Boolean`, `String` and `ArrayList<String>` types as values. I would like to determine the data type of the value at runtime and properly cast it.

Comment: Why did you mix multiple types into your Map? You could use `instance of` but it's going to require you test every element.

Comment: You could test `value != null` first and then call `value.getClass()`. What do you need that for?

Comment: I get JSON data back after rest ws call and the data contains mix of boolean, string, arraylist type. I converted JSON to java object (hashMap) for later use within a program. Then I realized that I need to determine its type during runtime. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch: your advice worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use an object mapper like Jackson or GSON to convert between json and your object and not do it manually.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I actually used ObjectMapper from Jackson to convert JSON to Java HashMap.